# SDL Window Disappears on Movement?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

I am writing a program with the `SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS` window flag. Now I want to move the window freely, but I as you know can't as you don't have a window bar in `BORDERLESS` mode. I came up with the idea of moving the window with the arrow keys. At first this worked wonderfully, but when it came time to display an image. `BMP` to be exact; the window, the second one of the arrow keys were pressed, the window disappears.

I have tried to change the code all I can but I can't seem to figure out what causes the window to disappear? Nothing seems to work. Does anyone know what causes with and how to fix it?

```
int right;
int down;

bool isquit = false;
SDL_Event event;
while (!isquit) {
   if (SDL_PollEvent( & event)) {
       switch(event.key.keysym.sym) {
              case SDL_QUIT:
                   isquit = true;
                   break;
              case SDLK_RIGHT:
                   right = right + 10;

                   SDL_SetWindowPosition(window, right, down);
                   break;
              case SDLK_DOWN:
                   down = down + 10;

                   SDL_SetWindowPosition(window, right, down);
                   break;
              case SDLK_LEFT:
                   right = right - 10;

                   SDL_SetWindowPosition(window, right, down);
                   break;
              case SDLK_UP:
                   down = down - 10;

                   SDL_SetWindowPosition(window, right, down);
                   break;
              case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                   isquit = true;
                   break;
           }
     }
}
```

Does anyone know anyways of moving a border less window with the arrow keys?

Comment: Is this in C or C++? Are you using SDL or SDL-2?

Comment: Under which conditions do you redraw? The shown code seems like a redrawing-free endless loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `right` and `down` variables are automatic locals. They are NOT initialized. So when you set the window position, it moves (probably a great distance) off the screen.

You should have your compiler warning level set to notify you of the use of unassigned local variables.

Comment: Wow now don't I feel stupid, all the code changes I didn't check that. Thank you very much!